# MVC 4 deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it a requirement to stop the site when deploying an ASP MVC 4 application?

I ask because I don't have access to the prod server but I'm in charge of updating an application.
We used to restart the site at my previous job but at my current one policies are different.

Answer (score 0):

We never stopped a site when publishing/deploying a site.